# Two men can clean the same house in $6$ and $9$ hours individually. How much time does it take if they work together?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Would you please describe how and why?

Two men can clean the same house in $6$ and $9$ hours individually. How much does time does it take if they work together?

Comment: Hint:  What fraction of the house does each man clean in one hour?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig hmm 1/9 and 1/6?

Comment: Therefore, together they clean $\frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{6}$ of the house each hour.  From there, you should be able to determine the number of hours they require to clean the house together.

Comment: If you're looking for a numerical result I doubt you'll find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: One man cleans in one hour $\frac {1}{6}$ of the house. The other man cleans in one hour $\frac {1}{9}$ of the house. Therefore together they clean in x hours the whole house:

$$\frac {1}{6}x+\frac {1}{9}x=1 \ \text{(house)}$$